# mysql using if and case statement to generate

Tags: mysql, sql

i have here a table name table1

```
debit  credit    groups

100               group1
500     -100      group3
        -100      group3
200     -50       group2
```

I need an output like this

```
group1     group2       group3
100         200           500
            -50          -100
                         -100
```

Here's my query

```
SELECT
IF((SELECT CASE WHEN groups = "group1"
THEN Debit ELSE Credit END),Debit,Credit) as group1,
IF((SELECT CASE WHEN groups = "group2"
THEN Debit ELSE Credit END),Debit,Credit) as group2,
IF((SELECT CASE WHEN groups = "group3"
THEN Debit ELSE Credit END),Debit,Credit) as group3
FROM table1
```

the output i get is

```
group1     group2       group3
    100         200           500
```

Comment: did you forget the question?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: I don't see a clear question here but I would suggest, based on your desired output, that you need to pivot your data.  Search on "MySQL pivot data".

Comment: @tale852150 yep exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try separating queries for credit and debit info and using `union all` to merge these columns into one grouped by 'group' value.

```
select
    case when groups = "group1" then credit end as group1,  
    case when groups = "group2" then credit end as group2,
    case when groups = "group3" then credit end as group3
from table1

union all

select
    case when groups = "group1" then debit end as group1,  
    case when groups = "group2" then debit end as group2,
    case when groups = "group3" then debit end as group3
from table1
```

Comment: Great!  Give an update as a comment.  Always interested in feedback.